# Regular Expressions marked subexpression

Tags: regex

Suppose I have a 10 letter word, say "HelloWorld". I want to recall the first 5 characters ("Hello") separately and the complete 10 letters ("HelloWorld") separately within one single regular expression. Is there a way to do so by using a single RE only? I mean by using the "()" metacharacter.

Comment: Please provide us with a sample what the result should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking for:

```
/((.{5}).*)/
```

Though the first group will be the whole word, the second will be the partial.

*Unless this is being broken down differently than an arbitrary number of characters*

Comment: You'll probably run into problems with that. You'll want to use the `$` metacharacter to denote beginning of line, or else you could match anywhere within the word.

Comment: @ChristianMann: Good point. I didn't know the implementation, I was more or less demonstrating the nested groups.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a version using just the regular expression syntax supported by *sed*(1):

```
$ echo HelloWorld | sed 's/^\(.....\).*$/First: "\1" All: "&"/'
First: "Hello" All: "HelloWorld"
```